# Transform rotation element - Keep on left side

Tags: css

I used `transform: rotate(-90deg)` to rotate a button. It's work well, my button is rotated.

Before my button was close fitting to the left side of the screen. Now is rotated, there is a space equal to 50% of the width of my button :

```css
#callnowbutton{
        left:1px;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        position:fixed;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="callnowbutton">
        <button>This is my button</button>
        </div>
```

I can't fit it again to the left without give it something like `margin-left: -50px`
But that's not working because the content of the button can change every time. So it should be adaptative.

EDITED ---

I've add the snippet. I tried to define the `transform-origin` and the `translateY` but it's doesn't fit to the left side.

Comment: use translation and adjust transform-origin

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and include a [mcve] in it so that we can see the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif I try but it's doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7xDeNxbaz1

Comment: @j08691 it's done !

Comment: read my code again ;) you are missing something .. I never said `left`, I said `top left`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Are you talking about the `body margin:0` ? It's doesn't change

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah indeed ! But in my case i have to put it at the middle of the left side

Comment: maybe you can add something like `top:50%` and adjust it https://jsfiddle.net/73kLbw7y/1/ ... you need to try things :)

Comment: Yeah i see, indeed. Thank's ;)